# RxJava Observable minimum execution time

Tags: java, rx-java, reactivex

I have an Observable (which obtains data from network).
The problem is that observable can be fast or slow depending on network conditions.

I show progress widget, when observable is executing, and hide it when observable completes. When the network is fast - progress flikers (appears and disappears). I want to set minimum execution time of observable to 1 second. How can I do that?

"Delay" operator is not an option because it will delay even for slow network.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Observable.zip()` for that. Given

```
Observable<Response> network = ...
```

One can do

```
Observable<Integer> readyNotification = Observable.just(42).delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Observable delayedNetwork = network.zipWith(readyNotification, 
                                                (response, notUsed) -> response);
```

Comment: 1) Why not use just `timer`?
2) Note, that network may fail before timeout. If you want to ensure, that timeout is always used, try `mergeDelayError` and then use for example `reduce` to transform two items into one.

Comment: 2) can be solved with materialize() right after network, and dematerialize() after zipWith(). Not sure about relevance of mergeDelayError() to proposed solution - you could comment original question or add it as another answer

Comment: `mergeWithDelay` will ensure, that if one sequence breaks, another sequence either successfully completes or return error (and not unsubscribed prematurely). Depends on what question author wants to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Observable.concatEager()`

It allows you to force one stream to complete after another (concat operator), but also kick off the network request immediately without having to wait for the first argument observable to complete (concatEager):

```
Observable<Response> responseObservable = ...;

Observable<Response> responseWithMinDelay = Observable.concatEager(
                    Observable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).ignoreElements(),
                    responseObservable
).cast(Response.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looked like Observable.zip would be a reasonable approach, and it seemed to work well until there was an error emitted; then it didn't wait for the expected time.

This seemed to work well for me:

```
Observable.mergeDelayError(
        useCase.execute(), // can return Unit or throw error
        Observable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
)
.reduce { _, _ -> Unit }
.doOnError { /* will wait at least 1 second */ }
.subscribe { /* will wait at least 1 second */ }
```

Comment: I had same problem with error!