# RxJava Single minimum execution time

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

I'm trying to show a progress bar in the UI for a minimum of 3 seconds during a network request.

The same methods described in this answer don't seem to work with a Single.
[RxJava Observable minimum execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38061463/rxjava-observable-minimum-execution-time)

```
Single.mergeDelayError(
    apiGetUserSingle(), 
    Single.timer(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
)
    .reduce { _, _ -> Unit }
    .compose(schedulerProvider.ioToMainSingleScheduler())


private fun apiGetUserSingle(): Single<User> // Network request
```

But I see an error: `MaybeTransformer cannot be applied to SingleTransformer`

What is the best way to implement this with a Single?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `zip` operator:

```
 Single.zip(
        apiGetUserSingle(),
        Single.timer(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
        BiFunction<User, Long, Unit> { _, _ -> Unit })
```

You can avoid specifying the types explicitly if you use RxKotlin:

```
Singles.zip(
    apiGetUserSingle(),
    Single.timer(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
) { _, _ -> Unit }
```